# Should Service methods return anything to your Controllers

Tags: php, model-view-controller

In a MVC application should your Service methods return anything to your Controller?

Let's say I have a `Recognition` service and it has a `register($firstName, $lastName...)` method should it return anything to my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if `register` didn't work?  Does it throw an exception?  You do want to have some sort of signal that something didn't work or that the operation was completed successfully.

Having a `true/false` return for success/failure would help show you that something was done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And what do you think should be done in the controller if the register() method fails and returns false?

Comment: That is going to depend on your use case.  Redirect to an error controller, provide an error message to the view.  That would be up to you.

Comment: @Schleis , why should controller care if registration failed or not? The parts that are responsible for "showing" in MVC are Views. Basically - this is completely wrong.

Comment: @tereško The service returns a success/error message to the controller which gets passed to the view and displayed.  Or the controller stops processing the the request and gives the view an error message to display.

Comment: Controllers do not pass any messages from model layer to views: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MVC-Process.png It sounds like in your current setup you do not really have views. Only glorified [templates](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html)

Comment: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC114765.gif.  "The Controller, in modern applications of 2000s, is a module, or an intermediary section of code, that mediates communication (between the Model and View) and unifies validation" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

In the frameworks that I have encountered, the controller is passing data to the view (either a message or a model) for display.

Answer (score 0):

No, services should not return anything to the controller. The state of model should be checked by the view. If operation performed by controller failed in some way, it will only matter to the view.

Controller is responsible for changing the model's state. **Not** for passing said state to the view nor for reacting to the changed in model's state.